# What does Wintel mean in resumes and job description summaries?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-8, definition

When looking at some job postings for programming and Information Technology, I noticed many list or request "Wintel" experience.  Why do they need a new word for this?  Why not just "MS Windows" experience?

Wikipedia indicates that common usage includes **"modern computers and OS"** and the possibility of **AMD architecture**.  This still doesn't seem to explain why they would need "Wintel" instead of just "MS Windows".

So, what does "Wintel" mean?

Answer (score 2):

Wintel means any Windows operating system running on an Intel x86 architecture.

Experience working in a Wintel environment means experience working in a modern desktop Microsoft Windows Operating System, as opposed to other architectures like Mainframe, Unix, or Linux.